# Flutter pick image dynamically for web and mobile

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an editor which needs to work on both web and mobile. So the core functionalities will remain same but the UI part will change.

Within that core part I have a portion which works with images. As the `File` object comes from both `dart:io` and `dart:html` I am facing some issues with getter setters.

**Where I want to show the image:**

```
  Widget buildImage() {
    return Image.file(
      widget.item!.imageFile,
      fit: widget.item!.imageFit,
      color: widget.item!.color,
      colorBlendMode: widget.item!.blendMode,
      alignment: widget.item!.alignment,
      gaplessPlayback: true,
      excludeFromSemantics: true,
    );
  }
```

`widget.item!.imageFile` is a getter setter that I worked on the mobile counter part:

```
  io.File get imageFile => io.File(_image!.image.filename);
  set imageFile(io.File value) => _image!.image.filename = value.path;
```

But as now I will have to make the code work on the web version as well I tried:

```
    if (isWeb) {
      await _pickImageWeb();
    } else {
      // some code for mobile
    }
```

And the `_pickImageWeb()` is as below:

```
  _pickImageWeb() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      var imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

At this point I'm completely lost and I think I went the wrong way. Since till now I was my images from the path using getter setter and now in web the image picking is completely different.

Should I have multiple getter setters for both mobile and web i.e: `imageFileMobile` and `imageFileWeb`?

Or how to solve the issue in general. I have seen `file_picker` but couldn't figure out how to integrate the package in this case.

Comment: You keep asking the same question, but not listening to the advice. It appears that you are trying to do something impossible: create an editor in Flutter Web. If you want to target web you need to careful to eliminate any dependency on `io`, which won't translate to web. If you need it for compile time, and you are going to use `if (isWeb)` to ensure that those parts of the code are not executed in web, use `universal_io`. Fundamentally, though, your problem boils down to: how do you intend to write an editor as a web app? Even if can pick a file, how will you save it after editing?

Comment: I've already covered the saving the file part. Since I don't to upload it to a server. And I've been asking the same question but unfortunately the only response I have got so far is use `file_picker` in a comment and `dart:io as io` and `dart:html as html` in another comment. So I thought maybe I was not asking the right question. My question boils down to: I'm storing the selected file in `imageFile` which is basically a getter/setter method. Is it possible to do the same for web? If not what is a better way in web to have getter setters for the selected file.

Comment: And please do pardon my repeated questions. As a non native English speaker I tend to think that if I do not get a response it's probably because I couldn't phrase my question right.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a getter/setter in this context. In the get/set methods that you show, you specifically refer to io.File, which simply won't work. I think maybe what you want to do is to pick a file and read its contents as bytes - in a cross platform way. Is that right? If so, file picker seems the way to go and you just need a little bit of platform specific code to read/collect the bytes. Again, looking at your first snippet, you are using `Image.file`. That's not going to work on web. To be web-compatible, switch to `Image.memory` and load the bytes from...

Comment: ... the chosen "file" yourself (in the platform-dependent way).

Comment: Thanks storing the pickedFile did the trick. Although I get some issues about decoding but picking image and storing it in XFile and then reading the file as bytes helped. Thanks for the help. I'm also using the Image.memory rather than the image.file.

Comment: Can you please share the code? I am trying to upload files to an API and need the code to work on both mobile and web.

Answer (score -1):

dart:io doesn't work with web, and vice versa for dart:html, I would suggest using cross_file and store the result in XFile and use it as file.readAsBytes(), because flutter web gives fake paths when selecting files, so going with bytes seems to be the best option IMO.